# Advice with optimizing -drawRect: method

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, drawrect, cgcontext

I want to draw 31 circles with different stroke width. It seems to me that I can not reuse it, because I can not scale it, all circles have different options. These views are not static and when I push my view controller, I always have to redraw it.

**UPDATED SECTION:**

Here is a Time Profiler's screenshot of my `drawRect:` method in **CircleView.m** when I transitioned to view with 31 circles:

[image: Time Profiler screenshot: transition to view with 31 circles without any optimization] 
[image]

By the plan, user will swap the views a lot and it becomes quite annoying to wait redrawing every time.
    I have several custom container views. The other ~30% of time goes to loadingView from storyboard. Nevertheless, it seems strange to me, because now theOtherTimeWasteView has only one subView:DatePickerView, but according to the TProfile running time is 84ms and 100% is spent on `[super loadView]` method.

**MY NAIVE(?) ATTEMPT OF OPTIMIZATION:**

I tried to previously load once this view, store it in the parentViewController "combinedViewController" and reuse it all the time. I added property in **CircleView.h**:

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImage *imageCircle;
```

Then I changed a bit **CircleView.m** by adding a call `-createImage` method:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.imageCircle=[self createImage];
    }
    return self;
}

-(UIImage*)createImage
{
    CGSize size=self.frame.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 1.0);

    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    self.brush=0.6;

    CGRect frameOfCircle=CGRectMake(self.brush/2,self.brush/2, self.frame.size.width-self.brush-1.0f, self.frame.size.height-self.brush);
    // Draw a circle (border only)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, self.brush);
    CGFloat mainColor[4]={23.0f/255.0f, 12.0f/255.0f, 0.0f, 0.5};
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(contextRef, mainColor);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, frameOfCircle);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;

}
```

**combinedViewController.m:**
Here is my try to init first 10 circles out of visible area:

```
-(void)createCircles

    {
        self.arrayOfCircles=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            [self.arrayOfCircles addObject:[self circleViewWithRadius:530+i*35 withBrush:5+i tag:1014+i alphaParam:0.60]];
        }

    }
```

I want to addSubview in **CirclesViewController.m:**

```
-(void)addCircles

    {
        CombinedViewController *parentVC=(CombinedViewController*)[self parentViewController];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {

            CircleView *circle=(CircleView*)[parentVC.arrayOfCircles objectAtIndex:i];
            UIImageView *imgv=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:circle.imageCircle];
            imgv.center=CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2);
            [self.view insertSubview:imgv belowView:someView];
        }


    }

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
   [self addCircles];
}
```

a) Unfortunately, there are *no* circles added if I try the second way. I debugged with breakpoints and arrayOfCircles is not nil, image property of circle also is not nil. However, there are still no circle in my view. Is there any mistake in my code?

b) Is it a *proper way* to optimize performance via getting image from CGContext in advance? If it is not, I kindly ask you to ignore my 'a' question and give some tips how to properly acquire high performance.
Great thanks!

**UPDATE2:**
Links:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/EstBG.png
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAjSJ.png
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw0cz.png

Comment: When you profile the animation in Instruments with the Time Profiler template, what do you find?

Comment: @PeterHosey, please be kindly informed that I updated my question.

Comment: That's a highly abbreviated screenshot that pretty much only shows what is already obvious. You should be able to find much more information in the same outline, particularly in the descendants of `drawRect:` (the methods and functions that it calls, and that they call, etc.). Also, don't ignore your other top-level items; nearly 40% of your time is being spent elsewhere.

Comment: @PeterHosey, sorry I thought that it would be unnecessary information, because I have quite simple `drawRect:` method, it calls few methods and these methods were given at the beginning. However, `CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, frameOfCircle);` method is too time-expensive. Please, see update.

Comment: In my experience, Instruments's annotated code view is best taken with a heavy grain of salt. Please show the descendant rows in the outline view instead.

Comment: @PeterHosey, sorry for late comment. I studied tutorials to learn reading TProfiler's results, but even [Ray Wenderlich's one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode) does not go deep. That's why I took screenshots of different call tree's options checked. If it is not still the required screenshots, please, give me some links to TP tutorials and I will return by some time.